# css horizontal scrolling with bootstrap using ul li tags

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to horizontal scroll using bootstrap, but I'm not able to get it to scroll horizontally. My `li` tags just doesn't wrap the way it should (it's wrapping normally).

HTML:

```
<div class="container suggest">
  <ul class="thumbnails bsuggest" >
    <li class="span2">
     text goes here
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bsuggest
{
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height:250px;
    white-space:nowrap; !important
    width:100%;
}
.bsuggest li
{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    *dsplay:inline;/* For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
    white-space:normal;
}
.suggest
{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:95px;
}
```

I think I've done what its supposed to?

Answer (score 16):

In Bootstrap **2** you have to overwrite some `span*` styling.

The `ul` element has to get this css:

```
ul.your-horizontal-list {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

ul.your-horizontal-list li[class*="span"] {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Here is an [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/harianus/Bn4BE/).

Make sure that your CSS is loaded after the bootstrap CSS.

EDIT: Name it Bootstrap 2, in Bootstrap 3 you probably need to replace `span` with `col-...` or something similar.

Comment: This is awesome. Solved a huge issue I was having. Voted up and thank you!

Comment: Idk, in your demo, I use: <li class="foo"></> , then in CSS I write .foo {...} , it just work, Idk why li[class*="span"] is necessary here? btw, I'm testing on bootstrap 3. https://jsfiddle.net/truongnm/xsgjumuj/

Comment: @truongnm the question was to solve a Twitter Bootstrap problem. So using the `col-...`-classes. Your answer has good code, but does not involve the Bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 1):

On the line `white-space:nowrap; !important` in `.bsuggest` the `!important` needs to be before the `;`

Like so `white-space:nowrap !important;`